# SQL query matching minimum X row count within any 30 day range

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume table contains the following columns `name`, `created_at` which string and date types.

Looking for any help to make a SQL query that outputs rows within any 30-day range where there are at least 5 or more rows that has the `created_at` column of the table inside that range.

- The query can just output the rows or the last one in the range - whichever is easy.
- The 30-day range can start from today and go backwards or from the first row forward etc.
- created_at can be grouped if required.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an aggregation query with filtering:

```
select name, max(created_at)
from t
where created_at >= @start - interval 30 day and
      created_at < @start
group by name
having count(*) >= 5;
```